# Parent Window is NULL in CFormView (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a `CFormView`-derived class that has a button I am trying to call `ShowWindow` on. However, this call fails because the `m_hWnd` variable is null. Why is m_hWnd null? The dialog has the `child` style set in the properties window, and I'm associating the parent `CFrameWnd` with the form view. This view is intended to be modeless.

Code that creates view:

```
void CMainFrame::SwitchEditView(CRuntimeClass * pViewClass)
{
    context.m_pNewViewClass=pViewClass;
    context.m_pCurrentDoc=pDoc;
    context.m_pNewDocTemplate=NULL;
    context.m_pLastView=NULL;
    context.m_pCurrentFrame=this;

    m_subSplitter.CreateView(0,1,pViewClass,CSize(0,0), &context); // create new view and add it to the splitter window
}
```

The constructor for my CFormView-derived class:

```
CDFAManEditViewProject::CDFAManEditViewProject()
: CFormView(CDFAManEditViewProject::IDD)
{
    // c_btnEdit is a CButton MFC control
    c_btnEdit.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); // this call fails on ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) )
}
```

Comment: The question title states that the parent window's `HWND` is `NULL`. The code you posted, however, indicates that it is the `HWND` encapsulated by `c_btnEdit` that is `NULL`. Regardless of this, as Scott already answered, the MFC (or really any class library) object's lifetime usually do not coincide with the lifetime of the encapsulated native window. There is a lot of overlap, but at the beginning and end you should be cautious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an edit control from the view constructor. But the view window has not been created yet when the constructor runs. That is why you have no m_hWnd and no edit control yet.

Move your initialization of controls into the view's OnInitialUpdate.

Comment: Oi, I should have guessed that. Thank you!